# Where to get standalone download of OpenOffice.org Math

Tags: download

From http://www.openoffice.org/product/math.html I know Math is OpenOffice.org's component for mathematical equations. It can also be used stand-alone. But I can't find a download link of Math for stand-alone.

BTW, http://openoffice.org/projects/www/downloads does not have a download link for just the Math component.

Answer (score 2):

[Openoffice forums](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=226) seems to indicate you need to download the whole package and install only the components you need.

If you wanted a standalone math processing option, perhaps go for something like m[athcast](http://mathcast.sourceforge.net/home.html) or something that supports [mathml](http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/mathml_software_cat_editors.html) ?